# Kendo-ui-angular2 controls not working in .NET 4.5 application

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In my .NET 4.5 I have setup my angular2 application. I also included all the libraries that are required for angular2 in my application. Now the angular2 app runs fine on my .NET application. Then to start using kendo controls I have included all the required @progress/kendo-angular -* libs in my package.json. I just used one kendo button in my component and when I run it throws the below error. In console - unable to load http://localhost:59086/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.  Please post the error as a quote within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to configure systemjs to include new packages.
As you can see on simple plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview you have a systemjs.config.ts file with a package configuration related to @progress modules:

```
packages: {

      '@progress/kendo-data-query': {
        main: 'dist/cdn/js/kendo-data-query.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      '@progress/kendo-drawing': {
        main: 'dist/es/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      '@progress/kendo-file-saver': {
        main: 'dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': {
        main: 'dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-intl.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n': {
        main: 'dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-l10n.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
```

Just to know....are you using systemjs as module loader?

Comment: Hey quick question. Can I use the previous kendo libraries in Angular 2 project as Kendo library for Angular 2 doesn't have all the features.

Comment: Yes sure but you have to import Kendo Jquery UI directly and work with ElementRef and direct DOM manipulation in Angular 2